# How do I implement double click feature to move camera back to previous position?

Tags: c#, camera, unity-game-engine, mouse, double-click

So I have several objects, when I click on one object, the camera zooms in and moves to that object. Then I click on that object and the camera moves to another coordinate where another object is located. However, I would like the user to trace back to the original object and then back to the initial position of the camera. So, I was thinking about implementing a double click to have the camera move back to the original position.

I tried looking for a double click reference and I tried to attach this script to my object. However, nothing happens and I'm not sure why. I even set the camera to main camera.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DoubleClickBack : MonoBehaviour {     
    public Camera mainCam;     
    float doubleClickStart = 0;

   void CheckDoubleClick() { 

    void OnMouseUp() {     
        if ((Time.time - doubleClickStart) < 0.3f) {   
            this.OnDoubleClick();     
            doubleClickStart = -1;     
        }
        else {     
            doubleClickStart = Time.time;
        }
    }
}

    void OnDoubleClick() {
        Debug.Log("Double Clicked!");     
        mainCam.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 1, -7);     
        Camera.main.orthographicSize = 0.4f;
    }     
}
```

I have even tried to implement a space bar approach instead below and nothing happens as well. I wonder what I am doing wrong. Should there be attached to the object in the inspector window besides the script, animator and box collider?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SpaceMove : MonoBehaviour {    
    public Camera mainCam;  
    void CheckSpace() {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
            print("space key was pressed");

        mainCam.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 1, -8);         
        Camera.main.orthographicSize = 0.4f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem. I forgot to call the function inside Update(). Here's the solution in case anyone is interested:

This is what I currently have running:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DoubleClickBack : MonoBehaviour {     
public Camera mainCam;     
float doubleClickStart = 0;

void CheckDoubleClick() { 

void OnMouseUp() {     
    if ((Time.time - doubleClickStart) < 0.3f) {   
        this.OnDoubleClick();     
        doubleClickStart = -1;     
    }
    else {     
        doubleClickStart = Time.time;
    }
}
}

void OnDoubleClick() {
    Debug.Log("Double Clicked!");     
    mainCam.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 1, -7);     
    Camera.main.orthographicSize = 0.4f;
}     
}
```

Also, I changed Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) to  Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0).

Answer (score 0):

It's not calling OnMouseUp(), which means these might be happening:

- OnMouseUp() is called on the script attached to the object that received the click, so you may have forgot to add the script to that particular object;
- The object that was clicked doesn't have a collider.

Since this is a functionality that you may want to make it work with many objects, maybe you want to make it work to any click, even when it doesn't hit anything. This is an example of how you could do it if you want it to work always, with the advantage that you don't need to attach to every object, only one:

```
void Update() 
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        Debug.Log("Pressed left click.");
        CheckDoubleClick();
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
    {
        Debug.Log("Pressed right click.");
        CheckDoubleClick();
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(2))
    {
        Debug.Log("Pressed middle click.");
        CheckDoubleClick();
    }
}

private void CheckDoubleClick()
{
    if ((Time.time - doubleClickStart) < 0.3f)
    {
        this.OnDoubleClick();
        doubleClickStart = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        doubleClickStart = Time.time;
    }
}
```